# macOS: Switch to last active window

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, spaces

When task switching from Google Chrome to another window and then back to Chrome I am taken to a different Chrome window rather than the window I was originally on.

E.g. scenario:

- I have 3 desktop. I'm on Chrome, there's 3 open windows and I'm on window 3 on Desktop 3.
- I <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to Terminal, then <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> back to Chrome. However it doesn't take me to the window I was on, but takes me to window 1 on Desktop 1.

I don't see this happening in Safari. I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.2.

Comment: Was the d3w3 in full screen mode ?

Comment: Isn't the keyboard shortcut Cmd-Tab?

Comment: @Benj yes my bad.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, nope.